# Member function of a class isn't recognized in a function

Tags: c++

I'm having a clss student and I used it's member functions in same header of the repository without problem... but now in this function I get an error:

```
..\StudentRepository.cpp:22:7: error: request for member 'setName' in 'st', which is of non-class type 'Student()'
```

And this is the function:

```
void StudentRepository::loadStudents(){
    ifstream fl;
    fl.open("studs.txt");
    Student st();
    string s,ss;
    int loc;
    if(fl.is_open()){
        while(!(fl.eof())){
            getline(fl,s);
            loc = s.find(",");
            ss = s.substr(0,loc);
            st.setName(ss);

        }
    }
    else{
        cout<<"~~~ File couldn't be open! ~~~"<<endl;
    }
    fl.close();

}
```

I have to mention that in the same file I do use them for example this function:

```
 void StudentRepository::editStudent(Student A){
    int i;
    i = findByName(A.getName());
    if( i != 0 || i != NULL){
        students[i].setGroup(A.getGroup());
        students[i].setId(A.getID());
    }
    else{
        throw RepoException("The name does not exist!");
    }
    saveStudents();
}
```

Comment: THIS....ISSSS...C++'s most vexing parse!

Comment: Do yourself a favor, compile with clang.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 Student st();
```

should be:

```
 Student st;
```

`Student st();` does not create an object `st` of the type `Student` it declares a function by the name `st` which takes no parameters and returns a `Student` object.

This is sometimes called **Most Vexing Parse** in C++.

Answer (score 4):

Remove the parentheses from `st`'s declaration.

```
Student st();
```

- [Non-working demo](http://codepad.org/QTNsKSkr)
- [Working demo](http://codepad.org/Pour0zNj)